# JavaScript/MomentJS: normalizing dates to current year

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Does anyone know of a simple way to convert a date in the past to its equivalent date this year? Meaning, if I get a date string for 17 January 1984, my function should return 17 January 2018, and so forth (with a corresponding adjustment for 29 Feb.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the year part of the date without affecting the rest of it.

```
let myPastDate = moment("1984-01-17");
let myPastDateThisYear = myPastDate.year(moment().format('YYYY'));
```

Comment: What happens when you do that to Feb 29?

Comment: @Herohtar Moment is really smart. It'll change it to March 1 if necessary. Here's a fiddle proof of concept: https://jsfiddle.net/wso8sn8z/